# Is the full strength of first-order logic needed for dealing with equational theories?

Tags: logic, proof-theory

More specifically, if we have an equational theory $T$ (a set of equations understood as being implicitly universally quantified), are the (equational) consequences of $T$ that can be proved with substitution and the properties of equality the same as the universally quantified equations which can be proved from $T$ with these rules in addition to the normal rules of first-order logic?

Comment: Yes. This is Birkhoff's completeness theorem.

Comment: See : Garrett Birkhoff, [On the Structure of Abstract Algebras](http://math.hawaii.edu/~ralph/Classes/619/birkhoff1935.pdf) (1935)